# How can ternary operators be utilized in LaTeX?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

This is more of a theoretical question.

Is it possible to use ternary operators, like it is possible in C (e.g. `(a<b) ? a : b`), and if yes how?

Comment: Are you looking at using an input like `\evaluate{a<b ? a : b}`?

Comment: @Werner I'd appreciate an explanation on how this works. but I was more interested in how ternary operators can be used as a tool of programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes C only needs different syntax for `?` and `if` because it distinguishes between statements and expressions. programming languages that don't make that distinction or don't make it so strongly, can naturally use the value of an if-expression.

so you do not have to go

```
\ifnum \count0<\count2
  \count3=4
\else
  \count3=5
\fi
```

which is the analogue of a C `if` surrounding two assignments.

You can go

```
\count3=\ifnum \count0<\count2 4\else 5\fi
```

with the if expression providing the value of a single assignment which is the analogue of a C ternary expression.